AWS domain verified with link shortening
I'm trying to set up a link shortening service using Twilio and integrate it with a custom AWS domain. I have the following setup and questions:
Current Setup:
Twilio Account: I have a Twilio account with access to their link shortening services.
AWS Domain: I have a domain managed through AWS Route 53.
Steps Taken:
Creating a Twilio Shortening Service:
At this step, is asking me to provide the verified domain. (The domain is verified record type TXT ). When you try to set up link shortening is asking for CNAME only. (so changing it from CNAME to TXT you will get an email saying the domain is not verified because it accepts only TXT type and as HTML via AdminConsole )
Create the TLS certificate and private key:
How do I configure this part? Because if the private key is created in AWS by ACM it won't work in Twillio. How do I retrieve the private key for a certificate generated on AWS Certificate Manager?
Are there any best practices for setting up link shortening with Twilio and a custom domain on AWS?
Any help will be very appreciated it
I tried to create the certificate locally and associated private key locally and got an error "Certificate is self signed. Certificate must be issued by a Certificate Authority." I tried to import it in AWS but that didn't solve the issue.
Does anyone have set up Twillio's link shortening service?
